# jQuery: reference element in array of ids

Tags: jquery

I have a form that is filled with teams and scores. One of the inputs looks like this:

```
<input name="home_score[]" type="text" value="" id="home_score[]" class="admin-input-small">
```

As the user inputs the scores and teams I want to check the input to see if a given team has been added and what score has been input.

I cannot work out how to access the home_score array for a specific number.

I was thinking something like this would work.

```
var score = $("input#home_score[1]").val();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Fetch all the inputs or just a certain one?

Comment: The JQuery selector is based on the usual CSS selectors, that means `$("input#home_score[1]")` is not a valid selector. You need to find a css selector that suits your needs

Comment: `home_score[]` is not a valid `id` value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `home_score[]` is an valid id ([html5: The id attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)).

Comment: @t.niese: I think I was thinking of HTML 4.

Comment: I have a form that takes results from 6 football matches. Each home team has id home_team[], home_score an id of home_score[] and the likewise for away teams. As the user add the data I want to check if the "target team" (his/her team) has been added and if so how many goals were scored. Then I can use jquery to change a different part of the page to accommodate the number of goals scored.  Thanks for the input people.

Answer (score 0):

An [**id**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) has to be unique so you cannot have multiple elements with the id `home_score[]`

If you want to select the nth element having the **name** `home_score[]`

Then you can use the [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector: `$('[name="home_score[]"]:eq(0)').val()` or the [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function: `$('[name="home_score[]"]').eq(0).val()`

Comment: You can have multiple ids as home_score[]. they are put in to an array. I use them often.

Comment: @Ian It is **not** valid to have multiple elements with the same `id`, the specifications are clear about that. If you have multiple elements with the same `id` then it **might** work, but the result and behaviour is undefined and it will  vary in different browsers. To name `input` elements you have to use `name` and not `id` and only if multiple elements have the `name` `home_score[]` then those transformed to an array (this is not the  purpose of `id`), everything else is incorrect behaviour, you should not relay on this.

Comment: It's common usage as far as I am concerned. Each id is different, not the same. i.e. home_score[1] is not the same as home_score[2]. Also I have the names in array as well. There is no efficient way to treat data other than this. If you can tell me another and better that would be great. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Ian Multiple elements with `id="home_score[]"` won't be expanded to `id="home_score[0]"`, `id="home_score[1]"`, ... . An `id` is and `id` and has to be unique read the specs! Elements are allowed to have the same `name` and if multiple elements are named `home_score[]` then it is common practice of **server side** languages to expand them to `home_score[0]`, `home_score[1]`, ... but even that is neither specified nor guaranteed and language/library dependent. But both `name` and `id` will not be modified on the client, so you need to always query for them as they are defined in html code.